# Debian NFS Kerbereos (MIT) Mounts and grants share but permissions are messed up

Tags: debian, nfs, kerberos

I have successfully set up NFS/Keberos but are having trouble with permissions when a Kerberos authenticated user issues a write, which outputs the following:

```
philip@client $: touch /mnt/philip/testfile.txt
touch: cannot touch '/mnt/philip/test': Permission denied
```

Below is my full installation and configurations:

`mydomain.net` is a placeholder

### Setup NFS Server

```
server #: apt-get -y update
server #: apt-get -y install nfs-kernel-server nfs-common
server #: mkdir -p /srv/nfs/philip
server #: cat <<EOF >>/etc/exports
/srv/nfs/philip 192.168.10.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,sync,no_root_squash)
EOF
server #: service nfs-kernel-server restart
```

### Setup Client

```
client #: apt-get -y update
client #: apt-get -y install nfs-common
client #: mkdir -p /mnt/philip
client #: cat <<EOF >>/etc/fstab
nfs.mydomain.net:/srv/nfs/nfs-001                           /mnt/philip         nfs     defaults        0       0
EOF
client #: mount -a
```

### Test

The NFS share should now be mounted under `/mnt/philip`. THIS WORKS!

## Kerberos Setup

### Server

Update `/etc/exports` to reflect the new Kerberos share:

```
/srv/nfs/philip      192.168.10.0/24(sec=krb5p,rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,sync)
```

Note: I removed `no_root_squash` here.

and export:

```
server #: exportfs -ra
server #: showmount -e
```

Now setup up the Kerberos server:

```
server #: apt install  krb5-kdc krb5-admin-server #enter realm in full caps, enter fqdn for hostnames
server #: cat /etc/krb5.conf
[libdefaults]                                                        
        default_realm = MYDOMAIN.NET                                
                                                                     
# The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.       
        kdc_timesync = 1                                             
        ccache_type = 4                                              
        forwardable = true                                           
        proxiable = true                                             
        rdns = false                                                 
                                                                     
                                                                     
# The following libdefaults parameters are only for Heimdal Kerberos.
        fcc-mit-ticketflags = true                                   
                                                                     
[realms]                                                             
        MYDOMAIN.NET = {                                            
                kdc = nfs.mydomain.net                              
                admin_server = nfs.mydomain.net                     
        }                                                            
                                                                     
[domain_realm]
```

continue setup...

```
server #: krb5_newrealm
server #: vi  /etc/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl # uncomment /*admin *
server #: systemctl restart krb5-kdc krb5-admin-server
server #: kadmin.local -q "addprinc admin/admin@MYDOMAIN.NET" 
# setup principal for NFS Service on NFS Server
server #: kadmin.local -q "addprinc -randkey nfs/nfs.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET"
server #: kadmin.local -q "ktadd -k /etc/krb5.keytab nfs/nfs.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET"
```

### Setup Client

Whilst still on server:

```
server #: kadmin.local -q "addprinc -randkey nfs/client.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET"
server #: kadmin.local -q "ktadd -k /etc/krb5.client.keytab nfs/client.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET"
server #: scp /etc/krb5.client.keytab client:/etc/krb5.keytab
```

Then on client:

```
client #: apt update
client #: apt install krb5-user
```

```
client #: kinit -k -t /etc/krb5.keytab nfs/client.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET
client #: klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: nfs/client@MYDOMAIN.NET

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
11/27/2023 14:49:54  11/28/2023 00:49:54  krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.NET@MYDOMAIN.NET
        renew until 11/28/2023 14:49:44
```

I can now mount the NFS share with Kerberos Authentication:

```
mount -a
```

Note I have `nfs.mydomain.net:/srv/nfs/philip              /mnt/philip         nfs     sec=krb5p 0 0` in my `/etc/fstab`.

if that fails you may need to:

```
systemctl restart rpc-gssd
```

### Status

NFS is now mounted on client machine via Kerberos

### Set up philip to access NFS/Keberos share

```
# setup principal for Philip
server #: kadmin.local -q "addprinc -randkey philip/client.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET"
server #: kadmin.local -q "ktadd -k /etc/krb5.philip.keytab philip/client.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET"
server #: scp /etc/krb5.philip.keytab client:
```

then authenticate:

```
philip@client $: kinit -k -t krb5.philip.keytab philip/client.hyvanix.net@HYVANIX.NET
philip@client $: ls -ls /mnt/philip
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 philip philip 4096 Dec 26 07:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Dec 26 09:34 ..
philip@client $: touch /mnt/philip/test
touch: cannot touch '/mnt/philip/test': Permission denied
```

here are permissions:

```
server #: ls -la /srv/nfs/                  
total 16                                      
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root  4096 Dec 26 06:35 .  
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root  4096 Dec 22 14:35 .. 
drwxr-xr-x 2 philip   philip   4096 Dec 26 07:30 philip
```

root cannot even write to this directory.

If I `chmod 777 /srv/nfs/philip` then I can write, so this indicates that I am an `other` user.

## where to go from here?

I appreciate any help to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I have the correct domain in `/etc/idmapd.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `addprinc -randkey philip/client.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET`

The default mapping of Kerberos principals to Unix accounts only knows about 1-component principal names; i.e. the server knows how to map `philip@MYDOMAIN.NET` to your Unix account `philip`, but it doesn't have built-in support<sup>1</sup> for principals that use instances – so the principal gets mapped to `nobody` instead.

In general, **don't** use instance principals for user accounts unless you know you specifically want to. In most cases, `philip@MYDOMAIN.NET` is what you should've created for the user account (and, typically, used a regular password instead of a keytab). But if you *do* need user principals with an instance name, then you'll need to define mapping rules for them.

(And unlike service principals, there is no special meaning in using a FQDN for a user account's instance, except in some custom setups. More commonly the instance for a user principal would be something like `philip/admin` or `/cron` – an arbitrary string rather than a host name.)

Authentication in NFS happens at the SunRPC layer, so the principal→username translation works **separately from 'idmapd'** (which is only for username⇆UID translation and only used for NFS "payload" such as the UID/GID shown in `ls -l`); instead, the translation is done in 'gssproxy' (or the older 'rpc.svcgssd') according to standard libkrb5 mapping rules defined in `/etc/krb5.conf`.

So if you must use user principals with instances, that would look like this for MIT Kerberos:

```
[realms]
    MYDOMAIN.NET = {
        # Example rule for the "/admin" instance -> "root" user
        auth_to_local = RULE:[2:$1;$2@$0](.*;admin@MYDOMAIN\.NET$)s/.*/root/
        # Example rule for any instance -> 1st component
        auth_to_local = RULE:[2:$1;$2@$0](.*@MYDOMAIN\.NET$)s/;.*@.*$//
        auth_to_local = DEFAULT
    }
```

(...meaning "if principal has `2` components, then combine them into '`$1;$2@$0`' and match against the regex /`.*@MYDOMAIN\.NET$`/; if match, then do a regex replacement /`@.*$`/ with '' and the result is the username".)

This will cover not only NFS, but also SSH and most other Kerberos-based services (anything that uses the `gss_localname()` or `krb5_aname_to_localname()` functions).

One issue with host-based instances is that you'll need a generic rule that'll inevitably also apply to service principals, e.g. every one 'host/foo.example.com' will now be mapped to the user 'host'.

---

<sup>1</sup> (It might be because Kerberos cannot easily distinguish *user* principals with an instance from *service* principals that use the exact same syntax – or perhaps the usage of instanced user principals almost always goes together with a *non*-default mapping of some kind.)

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you so much for this excellent answer, not only which solved my problem, but went into full depth of the alternative situation.

Comment: However 1 question, I am curious, you say not to use keytabs for users. Ok, I understand that users are careless with files and a password may be better. However, would this advice stay true for a system account. My desire is to generate a ticket for `libvirt-qemu` system account and renew tickets via `cron`.

Comment: It doesn't really matter to Kerberos as to which one you use; system accounts can use keytabs (gssproxy supports automatically getting tickets for NFS from a keytab) while normal accounts _usually_ work better with passwords (as then you can have users log in through pam_krb5 and automatically get tickets for NFS).

Comment: thank you again!